# How to display quarterly data in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI report with a Date (slicer) visual like that.

[image]

In a Data Model there is a tabel 'Date' that corresponds to this visual.

[image]

At the moment there are only **Day, Week, Month and Year** dimensions in date selection options. But I would like to see that there is a **Quater** option too. If I select all date options in 'Date' table then the Power BI doesn't add a Quater option to the previous list but constructs a new visual with different styling (the weekday and month names are in estonian).

[image]

The Quarter field in 'Date' table is created like this:

```
Quarter = Quarter('Date'[Date])
```

So, my question is why Power BI doesn't add automatically a quarter option to the dropdown menu and are there any solutions for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try detectimg column as a date in BI Editor or you may create duplicate column of date to see quarter options.

[image]

You can acheive this my selection "Filter" Visualization and drag drop the qtr, month etc in field section.

Comment: But why the Power BI doesn't display a quarter option in dropdown menu if this data field is available and selected in data hierarchy?

Comment: If you detect column type as date. It will automatically create date hierarchy (qtr, yr, etc.)

Comment: It creates date hierarchy as shown in the image below. But I want that I could choose a quarter option from the dropdown menu as shown in the first image (Day, Week, Month, Quarter, Year). I don't know why it doesn't appear there.

Comment: From filter visual you can achieve the desired result as shown in above image.